# Passing clicked links in rxvt to a script

Tags: bash, shell-script, perl, rxvt

I start my browser [vimprobable](http://vimprobable.org/) in [tabbed](http://tools.suckless.org/tabbed) like so:

```
"`tabbed -d > /tmp/tabbed.xid`; vimprobable2 -e `cat /tmp/tabbed.xid`" [1]
```

I am then able to send all new instances of vimprobable to tabbed (and not have a new master window open), in other apps, eg., mutt, by:

```
vimprobable2 -e $(cat /tmp/tabbed.xid) %s
```

I would like to achieve the same thing in Urxvt.

Currently my `.Xdefaults` contains the matcher arguments:

```
URxvt.perl-ext-common: default,matcher
URxvt.urlLauncher: vimprobable2
URxvt.matcher.button: 1
```

I have changed the launcher line to point at a wrapper script:

`URxvt.urlLauncher: vimprobtab.sh`

Which is just:

`vimprobable2 -e $(cat /tmp/tabbed.xid) %s &`

but this just opens a browser instance in tabbed with the default search engine result for `&` (or `%s` if I remove the ampersand).

I have tried with other obvious variables, like `"$1"` and `"$@"` - they don't work either.

How do I pass the URL to the wrapper script?

[1] This also feels like [a useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html), so alternative suggestions would be welcome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The help text for the [matcher](http://cvs.schmorp.de/rxvt-unicode/src/perl/matcher?view=markup) PERL extension to [urxvt](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/rxvt-unicode.html)
states:

> When clicked with the mouse button specified in the `matcher.button`
>   resource (default 2, or middle), the program specified in the
>   `matcher.launcher` resource (default, the `urlLauncher` resource,
>   `sensible-browser`) will be started with the matched text as first
>   argument.

therefore, you need to set `URxvt.matcher.launcher` to a script that
takes a single argument (in sh-type shells, this is spelt `$1`) and
open it.  For example:

```
#! /bin/sh

exec vimprobable2 -e $(cat /tmp/tabbed.xid) "$1"
```

*Note:* It's advisable to [quote](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~uwe/lehre/unixffb/quoting-guide.html) the `$1` argument to prevent the shell
from interpreting meta-characters that may appear in the URL (e.g.,
`&` or `;`).